# How to detect out-of-bounds undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

If I understand [Why is out-of-bounds pointer arithmetic undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473573/why-is-out-of-bounds-pointer-arithmetic-undefined-behaviour) correctly, this program has undefined behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    int a = 0;

    // out of bounds pointer: undefined behavior?
    uint8_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&a) - 1; 
    *(ptr + 2) = 0xff;
    std::cout << std::hex << a << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any way to detect this undefined behaviour? I've tried sanitizers `-fsanitize=undefined` with g++-8 and clang-8, and more warnings with `-Wall -Wextra`, in clang++ I've also tried `-Warray-bounds-pointer-arithmetic -Warray-bounds` but non print any warnings whatsoever.

EDIT: I am never accessing or writing to any data outside the valid range. So it's not a duplicate of [Recommended way to track down array out-of-bound access/write in C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284293/recommended-way-to-track-down-array-out-of-bound-access-write-in-c-program).

Comment: Best bet is using an SCA tool.

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and friends. It's worth noting that when you're doing a `reinterpret_cast` you're assuming a *lot* of responsibility for getting your code right. C++ basically assumes you know what you're doing when you use a tool like that and won't get in your way if you're using it completely wrong.

Comment: ^^^^^^^ or that

Comment: Where exactly do you have UB in the posted code?

Comment: valgrind doesn't show any problem either. I'm never  *accessing* any data outside the valid range.

Comment: "Is there any way to detect this undefined behaviour?" - Yes. Knowing the language standard *intimately* and then *carefully* reading the code is one way.

Comment: What if you do access outside the valid range? Like `ptr[9999] = 0`? Remember, pointers and arrays are largely interchangeable, so instead of `*(ptr + 2) = x` do `ptr[2] = x`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is not a duplicate because I am never *accessing/writing* to any invalid area.

Comment: @martinus You do not have any undefined behavior. It is legal in C/C++ to use a pointer which is not the exact start of your data. Actually, I worked at a company where some people loved FORTRAN so much that they would allocate a buffer and then save that pointer - 1. Then they could access their data with `ptr[1]` to `ptr[size]`. It's legal. Just rather weird for a _normal_ C/C++ programmer.

Comment: It is illegal, and was the source of a very hard to catch bug on an exotic hardware with an old compiler